# Why does the validation for my codeigniter website fail everytime?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller code like so:

```
        $validation=service('validation');
        $validation->reset();
    
        
        $data = [
          'validation' => $validation,
        ];
    
        if ($this->request->getMethod() === 'post'){
            $validation->setRules( [ 'comment' => 'required',] );
            if($validation->run()) {
                $CommentsModel->save(['Comment' => $this->request->getPost('comment'),]);
    
                return redirect()->to('/someplace...');
            }
        }
    }

    return view('templates/header', $data)
            . view('templates/menu')
            . view('addComment', $data)
            . view('templates/footer');
}
```

Everytime my form is posted, the validation fails... even when I have something in comment! Any idea why this would be?

This is the form:

```
<form action="/Add/<?= esc($book)?>/<?= esc($chapter) ?>" method="post">
  <?= csrf_field() ?>

  <label for="comment">Comment</label>
  <textarea name="comment" id="comment" ><?= set_value("comment")?></textarea><br />
  <?php if($validation->hasError('comment')) echo '<p class="validationError">' . $validation->getError('comment') . '</p>'?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Comment" />
      </form>
```

Comment: Could you show your form?

Comment: You're not giving the validator any data to validate. Use `if($validation->withRequest($this->request)->run())` instead of `if($validation->run())` See https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/libraries/validation.html#withrequest

Comment: Thanks for your help @Marleen that's fixed it. I missed it because I didn't see a full example given, and I overlooked this part of the documentation because it talks about 'http' requests so I assumed it was something solely to do with http. Do you know if there is anything different when https is used?

Comment: The decryption for https is done at a lower level in the protocol stack, not by CodeIgniter. The data CodeIgniter receives is the same whether it was sent via http or https, so you can process/validate both in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Marleen, you have been very helpful.